# How to write a basic Perl script to call a URL multiple times w/ one changing parameter in the URL...?

Tags: perl

I want to call the following URL in a loop format, calling it once for each Stock Symbol listed in a .TXT file.  Where "MSFT" is listed below, this would need to be a variable that would change for each value listed in the .TXT file (one Stock Symbol per line).

https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY_ADJUSTED&symbol=MSFT&outputsize=full&apikey=1A4999U3ZOOGFQQZ&datatype=csv

What would the PERL code look like to run this URL Loop?  Or is there a better scripting language to use to accomplish this?

Thanks for your help.

Just starting on this one

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you having? Please show us your code.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use [WWW::Mechanize](http://p3rl.org/WWW::Mechanize) for similar tasks. I also prefer [URI](http://p3rl.org/URI) in case the symbol contains special characters.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use URI;
use WWW::Mechanize;

my $mech = 'WWW::Mechanize'->new;
my $uri = 'URI'->new('https://www.alphavantage.co/query');
my %params = (function   => 'TIME_SERIES_DAILY_ADJUSTED',
              outputsize => 'full',
              apikey     => '...',
              datatype   => 'csv');
while (my $symbol = <>) {
    chomp $symbol;
    my $url = $uri;
    $url->query_form(%params, symbol => $symbol);
    $mech->get($url);
    $mech->save_content("$symbol.csv");
}
```

You might need to wrap the `get` call into an `eval` and maybe retry several times on failure. Also, if you really made your API key public, consider changing it.

Comment: Error GETing https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_DAILY_ADJUSTED&datatype=csv&outputsize=full&apikey=1A4999U3ZOOGFQQZ&symbol=IBM: Can't load 'C:/Strawberry/perl/vendor/lib/auto/Net/SSLeay/SSLeay.xs.dll' for module Net::SSLeay: load_file:The specified module could not be found (LWP::Protocol::https not installed) at stockscript.pl line 20.

Comment: Thanks Choroba.  I ran the script but got the error I just posted above.  Is there a .dll missing or some other error??

Comment: Try installing [LWP::Protocol::https](http://p3rl.org/LWP::Protocol::https)

Comment: I installed the Strawberry Perl on my Windows 10 laptop today.  Should this include this library?  If not, what is the best way to go about downloading and installing this library?

Comment: `cpan LWP::Protocol::https` should install the module. I'm not on Strawberry so I don't know the details.

Comment: Can't load 'C:/Strawberry/perl/vendor/lib/auto/Net/SSLeay/SSLeay.xs.dll' for module Net::SSLeay: load_file:The specified module could not be found (LWP::Protocol::https not installed) at stockscript2.pl line 20.